# Finding a line in a Python string (not file)

Tags: python, regex, grep

I know how to do this with a file, you just do file = file.open(f) f

```
file = open("file.txt")
for line in file.readlines():
  if line.startswith("foo"):
    print line
```

But now I'm reading the output of a process like this

```
log = os.popen("log.sh").read()
```

This outputs as  a string, which can be used with print fine, but if I do a "for line in log" it splits each character, not line.  And, being a string, there is no .readlines() attribute.

My end goal is to be able to "grep" for a revision number in the log and print the line (and above and below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options:

**Option 1**:

```
log = os.popen("log.sh").readlines()
```

This gives a list of string that you can process exactly like you do when reading a file.

**Option 2**:

```
log = os.popen("log.sh").read()
for line in log.splitlines(True):
   ...
```

Answer (score 9):

```
for line in log.splitlines():
    # whatever
```

Note that you don't need to use `f.readlines()` for a file `f`.

```
for line in f:
    # whatever
```

will work fine.